# Trying to print every second line of a file in C

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to print every second line of the text file to the standard output that I pass in as command line arguments. The code gives me a Segmentation fault: 11 everytime I pass in '-e' as an argument in the command line but the rest of the arguments such as 'n', 'h' and 'V' work exactly how they are supposed. I was just wondering if anyone could provide any help at all.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

int option;
int x;
char line[1000];
char string[1000];
char evenString[1000];
char *fileName;
int y = 0;
int lineCounter = 10;

if(strcmp(argv[1], "head") == 0){
    fileName = argv[2];
    FILE *fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr);
        strcat(string, line);
    }
    printf("%s", string);
    fclose(fptr);
}
else{
    fileName = argv[3];
    FILE *fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv,"n:hVe")) != -1) {
        switch(option){
            case 'e':
                lineCounter = 22;
                for(y = 1; y < lineCounter; y++){
                    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr);
                    if(y % 2 == 0){
                        strcat(evenString, line);
                    }
                }
                fclose(fptr);
                printf("%s", evenString);
                break;
            case 'n':
                lineCounter = atoi(optarg);
                for(x = 0; x < lineCounter; x++){
                    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr);
                    strcat(string, line);
                }
                printf("%s", string);
                fclose(fptr);
                break;
            case 'V':
                printf("Name: Patrick Hessionn\nEmail: patrick.hession@ucdconnect.ie\nStudent Number: 16347891\nVariant: Head, Even\n ");
                break;
            case 'h':
                printf("-h: gives you the help for the head command\n-nK: prints the first K lines of the text file\n-V: Outputs the version information\n-e: prints the first 10 even lines of the text file\nhead: will print the first 10 lines of the input file.");
                printf("\nMake sure to format your input as so: 'Program name:', 'argument name:', 'file name:'\n");
                break;
            default ://'?'
                printf("Error!\nYou should format your input as so:\n'Program name:', 'argument name:', 'file name:'\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `strcat()` on an uninitialised `char`-array.

```
char string[1000];
char evenString[1000];

    ...
    strcat(string, line);

    ...

    strcat(evenString, line);
```

as it expects valid "string"s as arguments. An uninitialised `char`-array is not a string. In C a string needs to have at least one `char` being set to `'\0'` to mark its end. This is also called the string's `0`-terminator, or `NUL`-terminator (note the *one* ell only), or null-terminator (note *lower* cases and the *two* ells).

Initialise the `char`-array properly to become an empty string.

```
char string[1000] = "";
char evenString[1000] = "";
```

Or more obscure you could do

```
  string[0] = '\0';
```

or

```
  strcpy(string, "");
```

---

Also you *really* want to test whether `fopen()` failed:

```
  FILE *fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
  if (NULL == fptr)
  {
    perror("fopen() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* include stdlib.h for EXIT_xxx macros. */
  }
```

---

Another subtle pitfall you have here in case more is read then can be store:

```
           for(y = 1; y < lineCounter; y++){
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr);
                if(y % 2 == 0){
                    strcat(evenString, line);
                }
            }
```

This can be fixed in several ways. A straight forward approach would be:

```
           for(y = 1; y < lineCounter; y++){
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr);
                if(y % 2 == 0){
                    if (sizeof evenString -1 < strlen(evenString) + strlen(line)
                                       /* -1 to take into account the space needed 
                                          for string's '0'-terminator. */
                    {
                       errno = ERANGE; /* include errno.h for errno and Exxx macros. */
                       perror("evenString to short for another line");
                       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    strcat(evenString, line);
                }
            }
```

Same for `case 'n'`.

Comment: @EsmaeelE: Pardon?

Comment: its exist excuse me